# Как хранить в базе проходы по дереву?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть единица дерева. У нее есть father и mother. Не могу придумать как оптимально хранить и использовать родственные связи. Типа того

- Ребенок - тот, кому текущая единица является мамой или папой (самое сложное, на мой взгляд в плане хранения)
- Внук - ребенок ребенка
- брат/сестра - другой ребенок мамы и папы
- сводные брат/сестра - другой ребенок мамы или папы
- Бабушка/дедушка - мама/папа мамы/папы
- Дядя/тетя - брат/сестра мамы/папы
- Племянник - ребенок брата/сестры

Ну и так далее.

То есть в результате я хочу получить такую схему данных, при которой я могу:

- Максимально легко добавлять в справочник родственных связей новые элементы
- Максимально легко (желательно даже одним запросом) получить для текущей единицы дерева получить нужных родственников

Подскажите хотя бы схему таблицы родства. Я начну

ID/Наименование родства/......

база mssql

**UPD:**

Почитал я комментарии и увидел, что не все и не полностью меня поняли. Попробую сказать другим языком. Я хочу, чтобы, когда я решу добавить новую степень родства (например, двоюродные братья), мне не пришлось бы перекомпилировать программу, а вместо этого я бы просто добавил в базу информацию, типа ("код", "двоюродный брат", "сын сестры/брата матери"). Вопрос только в том, как эти данные лучше всего хранить, чтобы было удобно их добавлять, читать, использовать.

Comment: можно сделать две таблицы: [люди] (id, name, bdate) и [отношения] (id, людиId1, людиId2, типОтношения, датаИзменения)

Comment: @iRumba Хранить надо конечно только ближайших родственников. Т.е. по хорошему нам надо _только_ у ребенка хранить двух родителей. Все остальные родственники вычисляемы. Хранить например прадедушку явно смысла нет. потому что при добавлении одного человека надо будет пробегать по всей сети и писать ему всех родственников. Вот как описать "степень родства", что бы по ней быстро найти кого надо и при этом не писать кусок кода на каждый тип родства - вот это действительно интересный вопрос

Comment: @iRumba Интересно, а кроме "отца" и "матери" могут быть еще ближайшие родственники, в случае ЭКО или суррогатного материнства. Т.е. не может ли у "ребенка" оказаться "биологическая мать" и "суррогатная" ну и прочие экзотические случаи. А если на Европу посмотреть ... так там ситуация вообще жутко запутанной может быть ...

Comment: @Mike _"Вот как описать "степень родства","_ -- hierarchyId? _"ситуация вообще жутко запутанной может быть"_ -- да, без отдельной таблицы [отношение] мне кажется не обойтись.

Comment: @Stack я и хочу таблицу отношений... однако не уверен, что мы видим ее схему и предназначение одинаковым

Comment: @Mike, не надо никого хранить кроме отца и матери. Все кроме них - вычисляемые. Вопрос - КАК? Про суррогатных я ничего не хочу знать. Так вышло, что у меня родители родные (то есть растили меня биологические родители). Повезло мне. И я думаю, что если бы у меня были приемные родители или приемный отец (если бы они развелись), то в своем дереве я бы указал кого то одного. Причем скорее всего родного. Ведь дереву все равно, кто там меня воспитывал. Дереву важнее кто меня зачал. И да, я не хочу на каждую степень родства писать свой код и я указал это в вопросе. Завуалированно, правда, указал )

Comment: @iRumba _"однако не уверен, что мы видим ее схему и предназначение одинаковым"_ -- если использовать hierarchyId, то сможете "легко добавлять" и "легко (даже одним запросом) для текущей единицы дерева получить нужных родственников"

Comment: @iRumba Ну хоть без Европы, это радует ... КАК ... Я сейчас работаю над этим ... На данный момент мне кажется что таблица родства с названием родства и таблица для вычисления родства, в которой для данного конкретного родства заданы правила, маршрут по которому надо двигаться по дереву... Вы про "сводных" очень удачно написали, сильно жизнь усложняют, но нужны :)

Comment: Почему нельзя обойтись одной таблицей: ID-Человек-IDРодителя? Всё остальное можно вычислить...

Comment: @iRumba, собираетесь ли вы поддерживать случаи, когда связи известны лишь частично. Например такие: 1) известна бабушка, но родители неизвестны 2) знаем внуков, но не знаем детей 3) знаем братьев сестёр, но не знаем родителей, и т.п.

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya _"Почему нельзя обойтись одной таблицей: ID-Человек-IDРодителя? Всё остальное можно вычислить."_ -- можно хранить в одной. и можно вычислять. а как? загружать таблицу на клиента и вычислять в коде? или вычислять в хранимой процедуре на основе рекурсивных запросов?

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya, все так, только родителя два. Большего мне и не нужно. Я же написал, что хочу все вычислять. Вопрос - как )

Comment: @Stack, к сожалению я не могу использовать этот тип данных. Все ID у меня типа guid и отказываться от этого я не стану по ряду причин. Придется найти другое решение. :(

Comment: @iRumba Серьезно пересмотрел ответ, все родство легло в одну таблицу. Что исключает необходимость повторного прохода по некоторым ветвям. И редактирование можно сделать наглядным - в виде дерева

Answer (score 4):

Нам нужны следующие таблицы:

**Люди** с указанием их непосредственных отца и матери:

```
create table people(
 id int identity not null,  -- ID человека
 fio varchar(200) not null, -- ФИО
 father int,                -- ID отца
 mother int,                -- ID матери
 half   int,                -- Жена/Муж (текущие, если нужны прошлые - усложняйте структуру),
 sex    tinyint,            -- Пол: 1-Женщина, 2-Мужчина
 constraint pk_people primary key (id)
);
```

**Родственные отношения**:

```
create table relRule(
  rid int identity not null,        -- ID отношения
  direct tinyint not null,          -- Направление шага: 1-Родители, 2-Дети, 3-Братья, 4-Супруг
  mask tinyint not null default(3), -- Маска ветви: 1-Женская, 2-Мужская, 3-Любая
  xmask tinyint not null default(3),-- Маска исключительности: 1-Сводные, 2-Родные, 3-Все (родные и сводные)
                                    -- Имеет значение только для движения "вбок" (сестры/братья)
  prev_rid int null,                -- Предыдущее отношение в дереве
  wname varchar(64) null,           -- Родственник женщина (название)
  mname varchar(64) null,           -- Родственник мужчина (название)
  comment varchar(64) null,         -- Комментарий
  constraint pk_relRule primary key (rid)
);
```

Дерево родственных отношений строится в виде ... дерева. На вершине лежат записи с `prev_rid=NULL` - ближайшие родственники. Любая ветвь может вести в одном из четырех направлений: к родителям, к детям, к братьям, к супругу. На ветви хранится название для родственника найденного по ней, мужчины и женщины, отдельно. Если *через* данную ветвь далее надо идти только по мужской или женской ветви, то такая ветвь разделяется на две, с указанием в поле `mask` пола родственника. При этом в названии родственника имеет смысл заполнять только одно из полей (соответственно полу записи). Например жена и муж делаются отдельными ветвями, потому как их родственники зовутся совершенно по разному (свекр, свекровь, теща, тесть). В сложных случаях могут появляться служебные ветви без названий родственников на них, служащие только что бы добраться до следующих узлов, в этом случае рекомендуется в поле `comment` указывать назначение ветви.

Для движения по дереву к братьям и сестрам есть дополнительный признак  "Исключительность" (`xmask`), он определяет оба родителя должно совпадать или только один. Для отделения родных и сводных.

Пример дерева родственных отношений:

```
direct=Родители(1), mask=Оба(3)                     = Мать/Отец
  direct=Братья(3), mask=Оба(3), xmask=Родные(2)    | = Тетя/Дядя
    direct=Дети(2),mask=Оба(3)                      | | = Двоюродные Сестра/Брат
  direct=Родители(1), mask=Оба(3)                   | = Бабушка/Дедушка
direct=Супруг(4), mask=Мужчина(2)                   = Муж
  direct=Родители(1), mask=Оба(3)                     = Свекровь/Свекр
  direct=Братья(3), mask=Оба(3)                       = Золовка/Деверь
```

А вот запрос, который по этой структуре ищет родственников:

```
with Q(rel_name,P,id,fio,father,mother,half,sex,rid,mask,xmask) as
(
 select Cast(NULL as varchar(64)),0 P,P1.*,0 rid,Cast(0 as tinyint) mask,Cast(3 as tinyint) xmask
   from people P1
  where P1.id=13  -- <<-- Для кого ищем родственников
union all
select * from -- <<-- Рекурсивная часть запроса
(
 select choose(P2.sex,R.wname,R.mname) rel_name,
        case when P1.father=P2.father and P1.mother=P2.mother
             then 2 else 1 end |
        case R.direct when 3 then 0 else 3 end P,
        P2.*,R.rid,R.mask,R.xmask
   from Q,people P1,people P2,relRule R
  where P1.id=Q.id and ((R.prev_rid is null and Q.rid=0) or R.prev_rid=Q.rid)
    and (  (R.direct=1 and P2.id in(P1.father,P1.mother))
         or(R.direct=2 and (P2.father=P1.id or P2.mother=P1.id))
         or(R.direct=3 and (P1.father=P2.father or P1.mother=P2.mother))
         or(R.direct=4 and P2.id=P1.half)
        )
    and P1.id!=P2.id and R.mask & P2.sex>0  -- Проверка пола ветви
 ) A
 where A.P & A.xmask > 0 -- Проверка Родной/Сводный
)
select Q.* from Q where rel_name is not null
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e19052/1/0) Примером выборки степеней родства. Тут же представлен большой пример дерева родства (пришлось транслит сделать, а то fiddle не выводил русский :( )

Comment: Неплохо. Хотя от маски исключительности я бы избавился и вместо этого увеличил таблицу в высоту, добавляя описания для каждого типа (двоюродные, троюродные, сводные по матери, сводные по отцу и тд)

Comment: @iRumba А как увеличение в высоту позволит определить, что брат сводный. Взяли мы брата по матери, но нам все равно надо проверить кто его отец... "Исключительность" как раз решает эту задачу, сверяет второго родителя.

Comment: Для этого можно использовать father, mother и sex. Меня исключительность не устроила тем, что не во всех странах есть такое разделение. Кое где, например, нет деления на сводных. А кое где нет деления на двоюродных и троюродных. Не создавать же мне для каждой страны свою таблицу

Comment: Ну наличие колонки в таблице еще никому не мешало. Если для конкретной модели не надо делить, значит там во всех записях стоит 3 и все. Это же просто признак, надо или не надо делать проверку father, mother. Как бы вы не проверяли это в зависимости от страны этот признак все равно будет нужен и он как раз тут и есть !

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать следующий подход (опишу схематично).

Находясь в каком-то узле дерева (а скорее графа) нужно обойти все связанные с ним узлы (а также узлы связанные с ними, и т.д.), двигаясь по осям *parent* (родители), *child* (дети) и *spouse* (супруг/супруга). Для удобства можно выделить ось *sibling* (родные братья/сёстры) как отдельную. В результате обхода сформировать (быть может даже средствами SQL) XML-сущность, к примеру, такого вида:

```
<person name="Я" gender="M">
    <parent name="Папа" gender="M">
        <parent name="Дед по линии отца" gender="M" />
        <parent name="Бабушка по линии отца" gender="F" />
        <sibling name="Дядя по линии отца" gender="M">
            <child name="Двоюродная сестра по линии отца" gender="F" />
        </sibling>
        <sibling name="Тётя по линии отца" gender="F" />
    </parent>
    <parent name="Мама" gender="F">
        <parent name="Дед по линии матери" gender="M" />
        <parent name="Бабушка по линии матери" gender="F" />
    </parent>
    <spouse name="Жена" gender="F">
        <parent name="Тесть" gender="M" />
        <parent name="Тёща" gender="F">
            <parent name="Бабушка по линии матери" gender="F" />
        </parent>
        <sibling name="Сестра жены" gender="F" />
    </spouse>
    <child name="Дочь" gender="F">
        <child name="Внучка" gender="F" />
    </child>
    <child name="Сын" gender="M">
        <child name="Внук" gender="M" />
    </child>
    <sibling name="Брат" gender="M">
        <child name="Племянница" gender="F" />
    </sibling>
    <sibling name="Сестра" gender="F">
        <child name="Племянник" gender="M" />
    </sibling>
</person>
```

Основная сложность будет именно в том, чтобы сделать этот обход, не зацикливаясь, не углубляясь чрезмерно из-за рекурсии и не создавая слишком много ненужных копий узлов, т.е. сформировать XML с достаточной и в то же время не слишком избыточной информацией. Предположим мы это сделали.

А далее, тип родственной связи - это определённое XPath выражение, взяв которое, следует выполнить XQuery запрос к сформированной XML-сущности, например:

- Родители: `/*[1]/parent`
- Мама: `/*[1]/parent[@gender='F']`
- Бабушки и дедушки: `/*[1]/parent/parent`
- Дедушки: `/*[1]/parent/parent[@gender='M']`
- Пра-, пра-пра, пра-пра-пра и т.д. : `/*[1]/parent/parent//parent`
- Дяди: `/*[1]/parent/sibling[@gender='M']`
- Двоюродные братья/сёстры: `/*[1]/parent/sibling/child`
- Тесть: `/*[1]/spouse/parent[@gender='M']`
- Братья: `/*[1]/sibling[@gender='M']`
- Дети: `/*[1]/child`
- Сыновья: `/*[1]/child[@gender='M']`
- Племянницы: `/*[1]/sibling/child[@gender='F']`
- Внуки и внучки: `/*[1]/child/child`

и т.п.

Что касается структур хранения, то, думаю, я бы хранил примерно так (упрощённо).

**Узлы графа** - люди.

```
create table People
(
    ID int,
    Name nvarchar(200),
    Gender char(1)
)
```

**Рёбра графа** - *ближайшие* родственные связи (храним только такие: родители, дети, братья/сёстры, супруг/супруга, остальные будут вычисляться).

```
create table Relations
(
    PersonID int,
    RelativeID int,
    RelationType tinyint -- 1 - parent, 2 - child, 3 - spouse, 4 - sibling
)
```

Comment: А как сводного брата получить ?

Comment: @Mike, сводных предлагаю помещать в `/*[1]/parent/child`.

Comment: Но в parent/child все дети, включая родных братьев. А нам нужны только такие у которых только один из родителей совпадает, а второй родитель - другой

Comment: @Mike, нет, в parent/child не надо всех детей. Родные в sibling. Идея вот в чём. Если бы у нас было обычное дерево, то находясь в узле, в одну сторону у нас поддерево children, а в другую цепочка parents. Здесь же в другую сторону тоже дерево (предков). Здесь мы делаем текущий узел корнем, а деревья child и parent вкладываем в него, плюс sibling и spouse по которым мы тоже можем пойти. Однако перебирать все связи не нужно, напр. шагнув в spouse стоит исключить spouse как дальнейший шаг. Шагнув в parent двигаться нужно преимущественно в parent, но можно sibling, исключая child, кроме сводных.

Comment: Хотя spouse/spouse тоже можно разрешить, но только если это бывший муж жены, т.е. не допускать явных циклов.

Comment: Мне примерно это и пришло сразу в голову. Сложновато обрабатывать и записывать. Вы предложили способ хранения, но попробуйте эти данные обрабатывать и добавлять через код. Будет много строк и способов ошибиться

Comment: @iRumba, вы меня не совсем правильно поняли. Я не предлагал _способ хранения_. В данном случае, XML-сущность это промежуточный формат данных, по которому удобно искать родственные связи. XML должен строиться _динамически_ и его не нужно хранить. Предположим, ткнули на человека в списке, запускается алгоритм обхода, который ходит по структурам данных, которые у вас уже есть (или по любым другим, главное чтобы они позволяли определять 4 основных типа ближайших связей), алгоритм строит XML, затем по XML с помощью XPath смотрим интересующие нас родственные связи.

Comment: @iRumba, по структурам хранения добавил в ответ.

Comment: да какая разница, как это будет выглядеть в модели представления уже? VM я могу и как DataTable представить или просто как класс MyTree в котором будет древовидная структура и нужные поля. Вопрос именно в том, как превратить то, что находится в базе в представление. И как отредактировать базу для того, чтобы добавились новые типы родственных связей без перекомпиляции программы.

Comment: @iRumba в данном подходе сохранять можно так: в xml добавляем нужные узлы (они будут браться из шаблона для конкретной родственной связи), отдаём xml хранимой процедуре, которая его парсит и вкатывает данные в таблицы. Как по данным построить xml я примерно представляю. Перекомпиляции не должно потребоваться, только редактирование данных справочника типов родственных связей и самих данных о людях и связях. В голове модель вроде бы сложилась. Я надеюсь, что у меня будет время вернуться к этой задаче, чтобы изложить подробнее. А пока, я вижу, у вас есть своё решение.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь, но я не воспользуюсь ни одним из вариантов. Мне пришла в голову другая идея. Может, она будет кому либо интересна.

Итак, есть таблица с деревом

id / fatherId / motherId

точно такую же таблицу (в плане схемы дерева) создаю еще раз, но уже для родственных связей

id / fatherId / motherId / Value (это название родства) / gender

заполнена она будет примерно так

some_id / father_id / mother_id / self / null

father_id / Null / null / отец / null

mother_id / null / null / мать / null

brother_id / father_id / mother_id / брат / male

sister_id / father_id / mother_id / сестра / female

А теперь вот в чем фокус. В таблице с деревом есть начальный ИД, который выбирается при инициализации, который обозначает человека, вокруг которого строится дерево.

В таблице родства он соответствует строке с Value = 'self'

И когда я разворачиваю дерево в любую сторону (то есть делаю запрос к таблице с деревом), точно такой же фильтр я применяю и для таблицы с родством с учетом пола (или gender = null, если пол не имеет значения). Как то так. Еще не осуществил, но должно получиться  :)

Если запрос к таблице с деревьями выглядит так

SELECT * FROM Trees WHERE id=@root_fatherId

то запрос к таблице родства будет выглядеть так

SELECT * FROM FamilyTies WHERE id=@self_fatherId AND id!=@self AND gender=@finded_gender

А можно вообще вьюху замутить

Comment: Вы бы запись для деда скажем привели. А то не получается представить что в ней лежать будет. Ну и сводного брата например

Comment: @Mike Сводный брат - mother_id такой же father_id другой, а пол male. Или наоборот. Дед - тот, что у father находится в father_id. А вообще надо столбцы называть просто Parent1 и parent2, а дед это или бабка, брат или сестра решать уже по полу

Comment: А "другой id" - это какой ? я это спрашиваю потому, что не представляю как вы будете два дерева сопоставлять. Конкретно как вы видя запись реального сводного брата поймете, что с ним должна связаться именно запись "этот id"-"другой id" за родственных связей

Comment: @Mike, это же деревья с одинаковой структурой. Это как проходить одновременно два одинаковых лабиринта. Смотрите на одну фигурку, держите две... смотрите куда двигать первую, и так же не глядя двигаете вторую )

Comment: я примерно понял что вы хотите, но все таки не доходит как будут проверятся совпадения условий, т.е. стоило ли вообще по этой ветви идти. И самое главное, не представляю как это изображать на sql и желательно в одном запросе. В общем маякните, когда более менее рабочий запрос будет, интересно глянуть

Comment: @Mike, маякну. Но одним запросом тут не получится... Если только с использованием хранимок. Будет два запроса с одинаковой (похожей) частью WHERE

Comment: Я вдруг понял, ваш подход очень похож на мой. Ваши id в хранении родства - это мои обозначения поворотов, 1,2,3,4. Только мой "поворот 3" (братья) + маска исключительности у вас фактически превращаются в три разных поворота, ну ли в два, если в случае если нужны одновременно и сводные и родные вы всегда будете делать 2 отдельные ветви на концах которых просто будут висеть одинаковые названия. Правда я так понял ваш алгоритм направление как то сам должен понять по этим id, а у меня направления жестко зашиты в запросе.

Comment: @Mike, нет пока кода. Однако есть алгоритмы обхода дерева. Если пока забыть про базу и просто взять структуру дерева в коде, то у нас получится 2 дерева: дерево людей и дерево типов родства. Есть узел дерева типа Node. У него есть value типа стринг, Parent типа Node (в нашем случае 2 поля Parent) и Childs типа массив<Node>. Так вот при разворачивании дерева я буду двигаться вверх и вниз, отталкиваясь от элемента, который типа я :)  И в обоих деревьях этот алгоритм будет одинаковым. Если мой алгоритм до упора тянет в родителей, то тянет оба дерева. Но из дерева людей я буду получать ...

Comment: @Mike ... имена родителей, потом бабушек/дедушек, потом прабабушек и тд... а из дерева типов родства я буду получать уже сами названия типов родства.