# Родословная в таблицу

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Есть база в Mysql:
FIO, father, mother, husband_wife, former1, ..., former10, baby1, ..., baby10

Пока в голове нет никаких мыслей как выгрузить это в таблицу с объединением ячеек по столбцам,
как на образце:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой подход:

1. поиск детей прадедушки, выгрузка их id в массив.
2. из массива поиск детей дедушки, выгрузка их id в массив.
   и т.д.

Получается не очень красиво и код сам по себе длинный получается.
Может можно как-то сократить этот код?

На картинке пример только одной ветви, на самом деле ветвей много.
Как можно сделать выгрузку в таблицу универсальной, чтобы rowspan подставлялся автоматически?

Если возможно, пример кода.

Comment: Это всё до тех пор, пока не поженится кто-то из дальней родни... а как оно встретится, так ты опять голову ломать будешь.

Comment: Я думаю, что Ваш подход в корне не верный. Вы не должны всю информацию размещать в одной таблице. Вместо этого должна быть одна таблица для данных человека, а все родственные связи создавать через внешние ключи и промежуточные таблицы. P.S.: вместо husband_wife проще использовать partner, особенно в нашем современном инклюзивном мире : )

Comment: Есть еще один вопрос: у некоторых родственников есть дети от разных супругов.

Comment: Это дерево. А значит надо почитать о том как хранить в БД различные деревья, а не вот это вот `baby1...baby10`.

Comment: "Есть еще один вопрос: у некоторых родственников есть дети от разных супругов" - это не вопрос, если данные о человеке хранятся в одной таблице, а связь с матерью/отцом (биологическим) указывается через внешний ключ на эту-же таблицу.

Comment: "если данные о человеке хранятся в одной таблице, а связь с матерью/отцом (биологическим) указывается через внешний ключ на эту-же таблицу" - это да, а как это отобразить в таблице, т.е. колонка "ФИО брата + ФИО жены" как будет выглядеть "ФИО брата + ФИО жены + ФИО жены1+..." - так?

Comment: Если прямо отвечать на вопрос, то ответ - никак. Т.к. как уже отметили в комментариях выше, кто-то может как Зевс - и дочь свою, а потом и внучку, и жучку, короче ваше дерево не является деревом. Дерево ацикличный и связный граф. А родственные связи цикличны и не связны

Comment: "P.S.: вместо husband_wife проще использовать partner, особенно в нашем современном инклюзивном мире : )" - нет никаких partner только husband_wife.

Comment: "... это да, а как это отобразить в таблице..." - у Вас проблемы с чем конкретно? Со структурой данных в БД, запросами SQL, отображением в GUI? "нет никаких partner только husband_wife" - а если гражданским браком живут?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485578/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%83/485724#485724

Comment: ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485578/… – 
Darth
 Спасибо, почитаю!

Comment: "у Вас проблемы с чем конкретно?" - 1. с запросом к базе, у меня получается их много: с начала скажем прадед + id его детей в массив, далее из этого массива - id внуков прадеда в другой массив и так далее, что по мне не очень красиво, думаю может какую функцию для этого написать; 2. вывод в таблицу - не получается правильно указать "rowspan", получается у прадеда объединяется 3 строки, а должно объединить 16; т.е. первая колонка 3 строки, вторая 7 строк и т.д. т.е. все съезжает.

Comment: пока  у меня все работает с BALKAN_FamilyTreeJS, а хочется сделать таблицей.

Comment: [Предлагаю продолжить обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150928)

Comment: "Предлагаю продолжить обсуждение в чате – XelaNimed" - я бы с удовольствием, но рабочий день закончился, надо идти домой, спасибо за помощь, завтра я буду в чате с 8.00 до 18.00.

Comment: @Анатолий Это stackoverflow автоматически предлагает, когда комментариев становится слишком много

Comment: эм... дык а и не надо именно таблицу строить. блочная модель с этим сама прекрасно должна справиться, не? рекурсией делаете прямой обход дерева, выводом строите дерево из html тегов - `<p data-header="прадедушка"><p data-header='дедушка'><p data-header='папа'>...</p>...</p><p data-header='брат дедушки'>....</p><p data-header='сестра дедушки'>....</p></p>` добавляете заголовки псевдо-элементом в css `p:before{content: attr(data-header); height: 100%; width: 100px}` и все... высота родителей автоматически растянется под кол-во детей.

Comment: "дык а и не надо именно таблицу строить. блочная модель с этим сама прекрасно" - Спасибо, попробую!

Comment: В чате общаться репутация не дает.